# sql aggregate function optimisation

Tags: sql

i am trying to find a way to optimize query which i believe is taking huge time.This is my sql query:

```
select
ISNULL((select sum(s.durationp) from Schedule s where AccountID = @AccountID and ClientID = @clientidvalue and status=2 and (@StaffID = 0 OR (@StaffID <> 0 AND s.StaffID = @StaffID)) and s.Date= @sunday), 0),
ISNULL((select sum(s.durationp) from Schedule s where AccountID = @AccountID and ClientID = @clientidvalue and status=2 and (@StaffID = 0 OR (@StaffID <> 0 AND s.StaffID = @StaffID)) and s.Date= @monday), 0),
ISNULL((select sum(s.durationp) from Schedule s where AccountID = @AccountID and ClientID = @clientidvalue and status=2 and  (@StaffID = 0 OR (@StaffID <> 0 AND s.StaffID = @StaffID)) and s.Date= @tuesday), 0),
ISNULL((select sum(s.durationp) from Schedule s where AccountID = @AccountID and ClientID = @clientidvalue and status=2 and (@StaffID = 0 OR (@StaffID <> 0 AND s.StaffID = @StaffID)) and s.Date= @wednesday), 0),
ISNULL((select sum(s.durationp) from Schedule s where AccountID = @AccountID and ClientID = @clientidvalue and status=2 and (@StaffID = 0 OR (@StaffID <> 0 AND s.StaffID = @StaffID)) and s.Date= @thursday), 0),
ISNULL((select sum(s.durationp) from Schedule s where AccountID = @AccountID and ClientID = @clientidvalue and status=2 and (@StaffID = 0 OR (@StaffID <> 0 AND s.StaffID = @StaffID)) and s.Date= @friday), 0),
ISNULL((select sum(s.durationp) from Schedule s where AccountID = @AccountsqlID and ClientID = @clientidvalue and status=2 and (@StaffID = 0 OR (@StaffID <> 0 AND s.StaffID = @StaffID)) and s.Date= @saturday), 0).
```

I am thinking each column of the query is executing same logic except change in day as last constraint. Is there any way i can calculate the whole logic first, like flushing that result into temp table and then query it with date as where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when s.Date = @sunday then s.durationp else 0 end) as sunday,
       sum(case when s.Date = @monday then s.durationp else 0 end) as monday,
       . . .
from Schedule s 
where AccountID = @AccountID and ClientID = @clientidvalue and
      status = 2 and
      (@StaffID = 0 OR (@StaffID <> 0 AND s.StaffID = @StaffID));
```

Note:  I left out the `NULL` conversion on the assumption that at least one row matches the `WHERE` conditions.